# How can I prove $f=x^n-a \in F[X]$ is separable?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

$F$ is a field and we have $0\neq n\geq 2$. I need to show that $f=x^n-a$ is separable, meaning all its irreducible factors are separable.

I first tried induction, but without avail. I couldn't figure out how to factor out $x^n-a$ and use the induction hypothesis.

Then I tried to look at $f$ when it is irreducible and reducible. It is trivial when $f$ is irreducible, and when it's reducible I let $f=p_1p_2\dots p_n$ but I don't know how to proceed from here...

I learned about the equivalence between $f$ having derivative not equal to zero and $f$ not having multiple roots in any field extension of $F$ and I wanted to use this theorem but I can't figure out how.

Comment: It depends on the characteristic of $F$.

Comment: can you please explain more?

Comment: What happens when $n=p$, the characteristic of $F$?

Comment: Oh I see, I should have put $0\neq n \geq 2$...

Comment: Have you tried showing that $f$ is relatively prime to its derivative when $F$ has characteristic $0$?

Comment: No, I haven't, but it's because I think the question already assumes that the characteristic of F is not equal to zero.

Comment: There are two approach : Either look at $f'$ and find if $f,f'$ are coprime. Or let $b$ be one root, the others are $b\zeta$ for each $n$-th root of unity $\zeta$.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments, there are a number of ways to possibly show $f(x) := x^n-a$ is separable. The most common are either to show that $f$ and $f’$ are coprime or to show that $f$ has $n$ distinct roots. I’ll do the later.

We will show that $\zeta_n^i \sqrt[n]{a}$ are the distinct roots of $f$, for $i \in \{0,...,n-1\}$, where $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity.

Recall that, for $i,j \in \{0,...,n-1\}$, $i \not = j$, $\zeta_n^i \not = \zeta_n^j$, so the $\zeta_n^i \sqrt[n]{a}$ are distinct. To show these are roots of $f$, consider $f(\zeta_n^i \sqrt[n]{a})$.

$$f(\zeta_n^i \sqrt[n]{a}) = (\zeta_n^i \sqrt[n]{a})^n - a = (\zeta_n^i)^n (\sqrt[n]{a})^n - a = (\zeta_n^n)^i (a) - a = (1)^i(a) - a = a-a = 0$$

Therefore, for $i \in \{0,...,n-1\}$, $\zeta_n^i \sqrt[n]{a}$ is a root of $f$. Thus, $f$ has $n$ distinct roots, so $f$ is separable.

Comment: You may want to say a few words about why $\zeta_n$ exists. The assumption $n\cdot 1_F\neq0_F$ is needed there. :-)